# DI/IoC with a Singleton Logger class

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, singleton

We are using an in house simple Logger class for our application's logging tasks (.NET 3.5).

The logger code is pretty old, and is designed similarly to this:

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{
     private ILogger instance;

     private static ILogger Instance
     { 
         // Initialized on first use.
         get { return instance; }
     }

     public static void Debug(string msg)
     {
           instance.Debug(msg);
     }

     public static void Error(string msg)
     {
           ....
     }
}
```

The instance itself is being initialized on first usage (lazily).

This is not a Singleton according to its strict "by the book" implementation, but nonetheless, the access to this class from all calling code is a ***static access***.

I would like, for testing purposes and for other architectural reasons, to be able to replace the internal *instance* with something else (inject it).

How can i achieve this easily? we are not using any IoC container at the moment, but i would not want to expose a setter to the Instance property since that would defeat the whole Singleton like design.

Any suggestions on how to come up with a solution for this?

Comment: `would not want to expose a setter to the Instance property since that would defeat the whole Singleton like design`. No it wouldn't. You can still initialize it with the default implementation. The setter would only allow you to replace it when/if it's required.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Fakes Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) for testing purposes. You could stub the call to static method with something like this

`ShimLogger.Instance = () => new LoggerMock();`

In case of .net 3.5 you can use [Moles Framework](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) to stub static method call. Configuration code will look something like:

`MLogger.Instance = () => new LoggerMock();`

It would require to make static method `Instance` public, but after this configuration every call to static method will return your mocked instance.

Comment: Is Fakes a new .NET 4.5 feature?

Comment: yes, but you can use their predecessor - Moles, which also can be used to mock calls to static methods as well http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, a setter does not sound like a good choice.

Instead, I would consider two possible approaches. First, an explcit configuration method:

```
public class Logger : ILogger {

  public void ConfigureLogger( ILogger logger ) {
     this.instance = logger;
  }

}
```

An advantage of such approach is that the intention is clear plus you have to call this method in an explicit way.

Another option would be to allow one to pass a type of your logger in your configuration:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="loggerType" value="The.Type.From, Some.Assembly" />
</appSettings>
```

Then, in your `Logger` class you rewrite the initialization routine so that if the configuration parameter is present, you prefer the type provided in the configuration OVER the default type.

An advantage of such approach is that you can reconfigure the client with the configuration change with no changes to the code.

Anyway, IoC containers don't bite. Introduce one as it pays off in a long term.

Comment: This is kind of what i have already thought of (roughly), but this is a bit cumbersome for unit testing (configuration file), unless it can be swapped for another config mechanism.

Comment: Look at the former approach. Frankly, you can provide both. Thus, in your `SetUp` you would just call the `ConfigureLogger` but in production, you could use the declarative configuration to swap loggers. I still wonder though why you don't use log4net. It can be configured programmatically or declaratively plus it has tons of other features you probably lack in your implementation.

Comment: Since i have a ton of code that already relies on this mechanism. That's why i am not using other loggers.

Comment: Well, your existing class can serve as a facade to an arbitrary logger. You don't have to change ANYTHING in the client code, just internally, in the Logger class, you start to use log4net (or any logger of your choice).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't roll your own.  I use the Enterprise Library for almost all my logging needs. It works on desktop and asp.net projects.  Asp.net can be a bit more problematic since you have to deal with security on the server but I've done it.

http://entlib.codeplex.com/

People also like Log4Net but I've never used it so I can't comment on it.

Comment: I have a huge codebase with gazillion calls to our own logger already. Redesigning from scratch, i would go for an open source of EL logger, indeed (after evaluating a few).

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the code using the Logger.  Instead of accessing the logger through Logger.Instance, pass in the desired instance of the logger into the object.  Then in your factories and/or composition root you pass Logger.Instance as the source of the logger in your production code, and in your unit tests it is easy to use a mock logger.

```
public class Foo
{
  private readonly ILogger logger;

  public Foo(ILogger logger)
  {
    if (logger == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
    this.logger = logger;
  }

  public void Func()
  {
    try
    {
      // do something
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // call the provided logger dependency
      this.logger.WriteError(ex);

      // not the static singleton property
      Logger.Instance.WriteError(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to make an `internal` setter for your `Instance` property and use the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute to make the internal setter visible to your test assembly.  Note that if the assembly that contains your logger is strong named, then you must specify the `PublicKey` in the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. Obviously this is most helpful (in the sense of not letting other developers accidentally - or on purpose - setting Instance to something else) if your logger lives in is own assembly or in some kind of infrastructure assembly where most development/logging is NOT taking place.